# How to fetch PHAsset from assetURL in Photos framework?

Tags: ios, photosframework, phasset, phphotolibrary

I want to fetch PHAsset using assetURL.
I used the following code :

```
NSURL *assetURL=[NSURL URLWithString:file.filePath];
        PHFetchResult *fetchResult=[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[assetURL] options:nil];
        PHAsset *asset= [fetchResult firstObject];
```

file.filePath has the asset url Im getting from

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager]
                             requestImageDataForAsset:asset
                             options:imageRequestOptions
                             resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                                             UIImageOrientation orientation,
                                             NSDictionary *info)
                             {[uploadingFile setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]] forKey:@"filePath"];}
```

But Im always getting the value of `fetchResult` as `nil`. Can someone tell me where Im going wrong ?
Is it because Im passing the wrong URL type?

Answer (score 0):

you can  use  this :

```
 PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions * editOperations = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc]init];
    editOperations.networkAccessAllowed = NO;
    editOperations.canHandleAdjustmentData =^BOOL(PHAdjustmentData * data){
        return NO;
    };

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        [asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOperations completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput * _Nullable contentEditingInput, NSDictionary * _Nonnull info) {
            if (asset.mediaType & PHAssetMediaTypeImage) {
                BOOL  isDownLoading = ![info objectForKey:PHImageCancelledKey]
                && ![info objectForKey:PHImageErrorKey] && ![info objectForKey:PHImageResultIsDegradedKey];
                if (isDownLoading) {
                    mode_asset.mode_fileUrl = [contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL absoluteString];
                    mode_asset.mode_UTI = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL.pathExtension;
                    mode_asset.mode_fileName = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL.lastPathComponent;
                }
                if (mode_asset.mode_filePathBlock) {
                    mode_asset.mode_filePathBlock(mode_asset);
                }


            }
                //                dispatch_group_leave(group);

                //                dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);

        }];
    });
```

Comment: I found  a question  ,call this method  lead to a problem  ，this  method can  block UI , wait the block call back,tell me ,please